# React Native: Stack Navigator Header vs Custom Header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

So like title says is there any point to turn off default navigator header and create custom component? Will it be like better solution, maybe better for performance or there is any other reason? Maybe there is some comparing list or any issues with default one?

Comment: You can already create a header that you want to create in the module. What's the problem?

Comment: @hongdevelop is there any advantage in creating custom one?